# Why is my Roblox jumpscare not appearing?

Tags: lua, roblox

Below is a Lua script that creates a jumpscare on the player's screen whenever the object "changeColor" is touched by the player. Problem is, the gui for the jumpscare does not appear when I touch the object and I have zero clue what is wrong.

```
local randomPart = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("changeColor") 
local baseplate = game.Workspace.Baseplate
local originalColor = baseplate.BrickColor
local jumpscareImage = game.StarterGui.jumpscare
local jumpscareAudioID = 629526994

local function changeBaseplateColor(color)
    baseplate.BrickColor = color
end
local function disappear()
    randomPart.Transparency = 1
    randomPart.CanCollide = false
    randomPart.CanTouch = false
    randomPart.Locked = true
end
local function jumpscare()
    jumpscareImage.Enabled = true
    local sound = Instance.new("Sound")
    sound.SoundId = "rbxassetid://629526994"
    sound.Parent = game.Workspace
    sound:Play()
    wait(sound.TimeLength + 0.5)
    wait(5)
    jumpscareImage.Enabled = false
end

randomPart.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)

    if player then
        changeBaseplateColor(BrickColor.new("Really red"))
        disappear()
        jumpscare()
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
wait(2)
local part=workspace.changeColor
local char=part.Touched:Wait().Parent
local player=game.Players[char.Name]
local gui=player.PlayerGui.jumpscare
gui.Enabled=true
unpack(table.create(2,Instance.new("Sound",char.PrimaryPart))).SoundId,Playing="rbxassetid://629526994",true
workspace.Baseplate.BrickColor=BrickColor.Red
part:Destroy()
local sound=char.HumanoidRootPart.Sound
repeat wait(1)until not sound.Playing
gui.Enabled=false
sound:Destroy()
script.Parent=game
Game:service"Debris":AddItem(script,1)
```